# how can I query last month data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get last month data from elasticsearch.

For example, today is 09/08/2019, so the last month data should be from 01/07/2019 - 31/07/2019.

I try to set the time range `"gte": "now+1m-1M/M"`, "gte" is greater than or equal to, it will return the data from 01/07/2019 (the first day of last month) to 09/08/2019 (today).

I think to make it query with the correct date range, I need to specify the upper bound using "lte" - less than or queal to. How can I define the last day of the month?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "now+1m-1M/M",
        "time_zone": "+00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: gte -1 months and lt now month, rounded to month?

Comment: or you can lt 2019-08-01 and gte 2019-07-01

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I would do is to add an `lt` constraint on the beginning of the current month, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "now+1m-1M/M",
        "lt": "now/M",
        "time_zone": "+00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```